# What does "shreds dirt" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across the expression "shreds dirt" in the following sentence in a story:

> Rocky is a rock star who shreds dirt with his guitar.

I found the following meaning of "shred" on "The Free Dictionary":

> To play fast solos accompanied by special techniques on the electric
>   guitar.

However, I am still clueless about the meaning of the phrase "shreds dirt with his guitar".

Comment: What *else* is troubling you?

Comment: Is "shred" used in a non-idiomatic manner? The story revolves around a character who meets many characters when he digs his land to rescue his kidnapped friend.

Comment: Could be, but that is not a grammar issue.

Comment: It could mean several different things.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](http://www.tahlequahdailypress.com/news/local_news/red-dirt-to-hit-the-ground-running-for-medicine-stone/article_b4638600-d3cb-51a9-a1e8-365cdd50623f.html), **shreds dirt** may identify the music style.

> We have three guitar players, so we're a little bit heavier than some of the other **Red Dirt** bands, so we sort of coined the phrase '**Shred Dirt**.'

Being [Red Dirt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_dirt_(music))

> a music genre that gets its name from the color of **soil** found in Oklahoma.